# How to compare two different sheets and place values in their respective positions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to compare two different cells within two different spreadsheets (One sheet is a base sheet) via VBA and if they are the same, take the values beside what they're being compared to and the place values in their respective positions.

So in the picture, A is a match in both sheets so the value of 30 is copied over to the base sheet. The spreadsheets that I'm dealing with are not perfectly lined up like the image.

[image]

Please let me know if you need more clarification. Thank you!

Comment: That is [*VLOOKUP*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) my friend. Check out the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented, you can use VLOOKUP in this case.
Assuming both your values are in Column A to B of both sheet and A1 and B1 are headers, you can try below formula in Cell B2:

> =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)

which will give you the result above. It is also assumed that your sheet names are *Sheet1* and *Sheet2*.

**Edit:** VBA Code

1. Using *Formula* Property

   ```
   With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
       .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)"
       .Value = .Value
   End With
   ```
2. Using *Evaluate* Method

   ```
   With Sheets("Sheet1")
       ' 3 ways to use Evaluate method
       .Range("A2").Value = [VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)] ' Evaluate shortcut
       .Range("A2").Value = .Evaluate("VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)") ' explicitly
       .Range("A2").Value = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)")
   End With
   ```
3. [Using *WorkSheetFunction* Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29849690/2685412) - Already provided by Tom

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for your response, but I should've clarified I'm looking for VBA code :(

Comment: @rmdlp You can do that in 3 ways. See my Edit.

Comment: For the initial parameter "Lookup_Value", would I be able to define that as a cell range and loop through the entire column?

Answer (score 2):

You can use native sheet functions in VBA. Just prepend the worksheet function with 'Application.WorksheetFunction'.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2"), Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A:B"), 2, False)
```

Hope that helps.